# Редактирование методов, выполняемых при нажатии на стандартную UI кнопку из кода

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно из кода редактировать выполняемые методы событием OnClick() или какая-нибудь альтернатива стандартной кнопке с такой возможностью.

Comment: Что значит "редактировать методы"?

Comment: ну так подписывайтесь на нужные методы, отписывайтесь от ненужных

Comment: `button.onClick.addListener` и `button.onClick.removeListener` - это искали?